# How to export Component for server side rendering in React

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, right now I am trying how to do server side rendering, I use Express.js as my server, so the code is like:

```
//server.js
var express = require("express");

var ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
var MyCom = require("./components"); 
var domstring = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(MyCom);

var app = express();
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.json({
        name: "new com",
        dom: domstring
    });
});
```

And

```
// components.js
var React = require("react");

var MyCom = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<h1>Hello, server side react</h1>);
    }
});

module.exports = MyCom;
```

I use babel to transpile the JSX, but when I start server, I do not know why I keep getting error like:

> Invariant Violation: renderToString(): You must pass a valid
>   ReactElement.

Could anyone give some clue why this not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your module exports a `ReactComponent`, and `renderToString` accepts a `ReactElement` (i.e. an instantiated `ReactComponent`).

In order to render it, you want to instantiate it like so:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyCom />);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. When I back to FB API, I realize it need to be a JSX style element too.

Comment: You can also do something like: `reactDOM.renderToString(react.createFactory(componentFile)(), {});` And it should work when your component lives in a separate jsx file

Answer (score 2):

Using a factory allows you to have all your components in separate files and instantiate them without using `jsx` syntax in your server. Very useful for the main wrapper component.

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  presets: ['react']
});

var express = require('express');
var reactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var react = require('react');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var mainFile = require('./app.jsx');
  var output = reactDOM.renderToString(react.createFactory(mainFile)({
    data: yourInitialData
  }));
  res.send(output);
});
```